# ¿Como acceder al modo de desarrollador en Android TV?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo pruebas con **Android TV** para instalar una aplicación desde el Android Studio, y no encuentro como se accede al **modo de desarrollador**. En otros dispositivos Android, a veces está un poco escondida la habilitación del modo de desarrollador, pero en Android TV sobre un Samsung Smart TV JU6500 no encuentro como activarlo.

¿Alguno sabe como se puede ingresar al **modo desarrollado en Android TV**?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí se explica como activarlo genéricamente:

http://corochann.com/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-android-tv-216.html

Pasos:

`Ajustes` / `Acerca` / `Build` / `Opciones de desarrollador`

Comment: Hola +edur, gracias por la orientación, si, tiene el sistema operativo Tizen, o sea que no es el Android TV, por la cual voy a tener que empezar de cero a ver como se desarrolla sobre esa plataforma... esto no lo sabia... saludos

Comment: Esto es lo que estaba buscando: ingreso al modo desarrollador en Tizen:1) Make sure my PC and TV are on the same local network
2) Turn on TV ==> Go to Apps ==> Pressed 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
3) Turn ON developer mode. Entered the PC's IP address. Pressed OK
4) Then, I rebooted my TV.